# Firefox OS on android emulator, testing sms error

Tags: android, testing, android-emulator, sms, firefox-os

I have Firefox OS on android emulator.

When I send sms from emulator, I want get different errors for testing.

Is there a way to test various errors coming from android modem after fail sending sms?

When I send sms via emulator, my sms always sending with status "success". How can I testing different error options? Also I can get error if I turn on "Airplane mode", but how testing errors from sms center and other?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you mean more detailed errors in the log? If so, you can try to enable relevant preferences ("ril.debugging.enabled", "network.debugging.enabled" and "mms.debugging.enabled") with https://github.com/bevis-tseng/Debug_Tools (based on ADB).

Comment: When I send sms via emulator, my sms always sending with status "success". How can I testing different error options? Also I can get error if I turn on "Airplane mode", but how testing errors from sms center and other?